# RSAParameters calculating private parameters

Tags: c#, rsa, .net-standard

I am trying to calculate the private parameters of the `RSAParameters` struct on .NET Standard. I made a unit test to test my calculations:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DQDPTest()
{
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    RSAParameters rsaParams = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(rsaParams.P.Reverse().ToArray());
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(rsaParams.Q.Reverse().ToArray());
    BigInteger d = new BigInteger(rsaParams.D.Reverse().ToArray());
    BigInteger dq = new BigInteger(rsaParams.DQ.Reverse().ToArray());
    BigInteger dp = new BigInteger(rsaParams.DP.Reverse().ToArray());
    Assert.AreEqual(dq, d % (q - 1));
    Assert.AreEqual(dp, d % (p - 1));
}
```

However, the assertions consistently fail and I cannot figure out why, since `DQ` and `DP` are supposed to contain those values. Why is this happening?

I have a similar method for calculating `InverseQ`, and this does not work either:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ModInverseTest()
{
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    RSAParameters rsaParams = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

    BigInteger p = new BigInteger(rsaParams.P.Reverse().ToArray());
    BigInteger q = new BigInteger(rsaParams.Q.Reverse().ToArray());
    BigInteger iq = new BigInteger(rsaParams.InverseQ.Reverse().ToArray());
    BigInteger ciq = Extensions.ModInverse(q, p);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, (iq * q) % p);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, (ciq * q) % p);
    Assert.AreEqual(iq, ciq);
}

public static BigInteger ModInverse(BigInteger a, BigInteger n)
{
    BigInteger t = 0, nt = 1, r = n, nr = a;

    if (n < 0)
    {
        n = -n;
    }

    if (a < 0)
    {
        a = n - (-a % n);
    }

    while (nr != 0)
    {
        var quot = r / nr;

        var tmp = nt; nt = t - quot * nt; t = tmp;
        tmp = nr; nr = r - quot * nr; r = tmp;
    }

    if (r > 1) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(a) + " is not convertible.");
    if (t < 0) t = t + n;
    return t;
}
```

The assertions in `ModInverseTest()` also consistently fail, which means either I am doing something incorrectly, or these values are simply not what I think they are. Again, why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your values for P and Q are almost certainly negative, which is likely throwing off everything else.  This is because the C# BigInteger constructor doesn't allow you to specify positive/negative, and so a most significant byte with the most sigificant bit set means it's a negative number. The solution is to add a padding byte (0x00) which keeps the sign bit clear.

```
private static System.Numerics.BigInteger GetBigInteger(byte[] parameter)
{
    byte[] signPadded = new byte[parameter.Length + 1];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(parameter, 0, signPadded, 1, parameter.Length);
    Array.Reverse(signPadded);
    return new System.Numerics.BigInteger(signPadded);
}
```

Comment: Please note that, at least in .net core 3.0 BigInteger has a constructor public BigInteger(ReadOnlySpan<byte> value, bool isUnsigned=false, bool isBigEndian=false) that handles all of this conversion mess for you.